# Proper Subset proof

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let $n \in \Bbb Z$ and $A=\{m \in \Bbb Z : 3m \mid n\}$

If $\{-20,21\}$ is a subset of $A$, then $\{3,10,-20,21\}$ is a proper subset of $A$.

Now I'm assuming that $n$ must be multiples of $3$ and ($n= 3 m k$ for an integer $k$), then $mk = n/3$.

But I don't know where to start the proof.

Comment: If {-20,21} subset A then -60|n and 63|n.  Does it follow that 9|n or 30|n?  Does it follow that there are any *other* 3m|n other than 3,10,-20,21?

Comment: Hint if ab|m then it follows that a|m.

Comment: There would be. Since according to a|m would entail that there are endless multiples of three. I hope I got the logic right.

Comment: No it wouldn't. If $n = 74$ then $A= \emptyset $.  If $n = 78=3*26$ then $A=\{\pm 1,\pm 2, \pm 13, \pm 26\}$.  A is finite.  We can't actually determine what n is but we can name many of its factors.

Answer (score 0):

$-20 \in A $.  So $-20*3=-60|n$ so $30|n $.  So $3*10|n $.  So $10 \in A $.

Okay, that's my hint.  If you can prove $3 \in A $, you have $-20,10, 3,21\in A $ so $B=\{-20,10,3,21\} \subset A $.

okay.  Here's another hint.  If you can prove  $2$ (or any other number) $ \in A $ then you know $B \ne A $ (because $2 \not \in B $).

Can you finish?

====

Here's an example.  If $n = 120=3*8*5$ then $A= \{\pm 1,\pm 2, \pm 4, \pm 5, \pm 8, \pm 10, \pm 20, \pm 40\} $.

$-20 \in A $ but $21\not \in A $ so $n\ne 120$.

Comment: Ahh! Okay I understand now! Thank you!